# How to implement a Rust function that modifies multiple elements of a vector?

Tags: loops, rust, borrow-checker

I have this code:

```
struct Physical;

fn collision(a: &mut Physical, b: &mut Physical) {
    //accelerate a and b depending on their values
}

fn main_loop(vec: &mut Vec<Physical>) {
    for i in 0..vec.len() {
        for j in i+1..vec.len() {
            collision(&mut vec[i], &mut vec[j]);
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut vec = vec![Physical, Physical, Physical];
    loop {
        main_loop(&mut vec);
    }
}
```

This doesn't compile, because the mutable references are both in the same vector.

It would be possible to change `collision` to take indices and the mutable vector, but it looks ugly. I also want to change the `Container` type later to make the collision more efficient. I may even want to use multiple containers for my objects, so this won't be an option.

How can this be done the best way?

Comment: I also found an answer using `RefCell`, but I don't think, this is better than in the link.